# Can I select a clip in imovie by specifying the start and end time? (rather than dragging mouse)

Tags: imovie

Is there a way in imovie to select a clip by typing in the start and end time (rather than by dragging the mouse).  I would like to make a precise selection from, for example, 0:16 to 18:02.  Is there a way to do that typing in those times.  Seems very difficult to get that precise with the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

There is Handbrake that does exactly that, in fact one can define the start and end point in several ways.

Just a user though.